# writing text on a txt file and ways to do it

Tags: java, arraylist, text, filewriter

So im doing MOOC exercises right now and it asks me to write a text on a txt file using a ArrayList.
I just dont understand why it accepted this code:

```
public void save(String file, List<String> texts) throws IOException {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); i++) {
            f.write(texts.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        f.close();
        }
```

but not this code:

```
public void save(String file, List<String> texts) throws IOException {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file, true);
        for (String text : texts) {
            f.write(text);
            System.out.println("");
        }
        f.close();
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println("");` doesn't write to the file but to the console instead. Your file won't have new line characters.

Comment: because the first snippets writes the linebreak to the file, the second writes the linebreak to `System.out` and *not* to the file. The question is why you would assume the second code to be valid...

Comment: ok, if i remove System.out.println("");, it would write all the text on one line right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also writing a line separator in 2nd code as :

```
for (String text : texts) {
     f.write(text);
     f.write(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, System.out.println writes to the console instead